# Compile error when trying to use Animator in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Compiler message:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animator-0.1.4/lib/animator.dart:457:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'blocs'.
      blocs: [_animatorBloc],
      ^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/states_rebuilder-1.15.0/lib/src/state_with_mixin_builder.dart:142:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.   StateWithMixinBuilder({   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animator-0.1.4/lib/animator.dart:494:27: Error: Method not found: 'StatesRebuilder.addToListeners'.
          StatesRebuilder.addToListeners(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animator-0.1.4/lib/animator.dart:559:27: Error: Method not found: 'StatesRebuilder.removeFromListeners'.
          StatesRebuilder.removeFromListeners(b, widget.name, "$hashCode");
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix by adding statebuilder package in pubsec.yml file

states_rebuilder: 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an old version of the Animator package. The updated version of Animator (2.0.1) works. The latest version needs 3 parameters in the builder function. [Answered here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659269/flutter-issues-with-animator/63671072#63671072)

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `states_rebuilder: ^3.2.0` will solve the problem